# Test Twitter REST API on localhost (php/yii2)

Tags: php, twitter, yii2, twitter-oauth, yii2-advanced-app

I have some difficulties with the twitter api on localhost.

I'm using the official Yii2 authclient extension - [Yii2-AuthClient](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient) and followed  [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/711/how-to-use-yii2-authclient-to-communicate-with-twitter-using-single-access-token/).

Everything looks fine, but when I try to call:

```
$twitter->api('search/tweets.json?q=%40twitterapi', 'GET');
```

I got the following Exception:

```
Request failed with code: 401, message: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

My twitter app keys are as it should be.

In the app page for callback url I've tried already the following urls, but without success:

```
http://local-project.dev
http://localhost/project_folder/frontend/web/
http://127.0.0.1/project_folder/frontend/web/
http://127.0.0.1:80/project_folder/frontend/web/
```

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

Comment: An HTTP 401 means that the authentication is not correct. I would suggest to check your api key once more.

Comment: The access token, access secret, consumer key and consumer secret are correct (double checked) + the twitter app has read/write rights enabled.

Comment: Are you able to make other calls?  What happens when you call https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials ?

Comment: @TerenceEden, calling $twitter->api('account/verify_credentials.json', 'GET') returns info for my account

Comment: check [this note](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/711/how-to-use-yii2-authclient-to-communicate-with-twitter-using-single-access-token/#hh3) from the tutorial you provided. I guess an `Invalid Token` is same as a `401` response. did you try to generate a different token ?

Comment: @SalemOuerdani - generated new consuper and access keys/tokens but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is an issue with the yii2 extension url params parser - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7224.

Using the array format works like a charm:

```
$twitter->api('search/tweets.json', 'GET', ['q' => 'twitterapi']);
```